# how to get length of array in Native script (vueJS)

Tags: arrays, vue.js, nativescript, variable-length-array

I would like to know how I can get the length of my array in Native script /vue JS?

My code :

```
export default {
    data: () => {
        return {
            i: 0,
            log: [],
            img:[
                "~/Pictures/home.png",
                "~/Pictures/test.png"
                ],
        };
    },
```

Do you have an idea?

Comment: What`s array length you need?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [computed property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html) for this.

Assuming you want the length of the `img` array:

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      img: ["~/Pictures/home.png", "~/Pictures/test.png"]
    };
  },
  computed: {
    imgArrayLength() {
      return this.img.length;
    }
  }
};
</script>
```